# How does Plug.Exception work?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I’m having some trouble getting a simple example to work. I’m not using Phoenix FWIW, just plug

```
defmodule Unauthorized do
  defexception message: "not authorized", plug_status: 401
end

defmodule Foo do
  use Plug.Router
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "heyyyo")
  end

  get "/boom" do
    raise Unauthorized
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "not found")
  end
end
```

This is kind of a silly example, but I’m just trying to see if it will work like I think it is supposed to work.

I was hoping that Plug would handle the exception raised in `GET /boom` and return a 401 status

However, when I do try to `GET /boom` it is returning a 500 status, so apparently the exception isn’t being handled by Plug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `use Plug.ErrorHandler` if you want to catch these exceptions and send an HTTP status code based on the exception that was raised:

```
defmodule Foo do
  use Plug.Router
  use Plug.ErrorHandler

  ...
end
```

With this change, I get the correct response:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:4000/boom
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
server: Cowboy
date: Wed, 17 May 2017 19:59:57 GMT
content-length: 20
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

Something went wrong
```

Comment: a followup question for you. How do I test this? In the test I can only see it raises the exception. I'm not able to assert on `conn.status`

Comment: You can use `Plug.Test.sent_resp`. Example from Plug's own tests: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/test/plug/error_handler_test.exs#L36-L67.

Comment: Yep, that is it!